# PHP preg_replace values that contain parentheses

Tags: php, preg-replace

In my PHP script, I want to use preg_replace to replace values, skipping any value that is within the HTML tags `<a>` and `</a>`.  The values are contained within arrays, so the following is a snippet of the current code that is run within a loop:

`$Used[$i] = preg_replace("~<a[^>]*>.*?</a\s*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|{$MatchFinal[$i]}~","{$MatchLinkFinal[$i]}", $value);`

The code works, except for values that contain parentheses `(` or `)`.

For example, if `$MatchFinal[$i]` contains the value `Fatigue`, then it replaces it with a value `$MatchLinkFinal[$i]` that includes a link: `<a>`...`Fatigue`...`<a>`.  However, if `$MatchFinal[$i]` contains the value `Hair (Dry)`, then it does not replace it.

**Why are values that contain parentheses not being replaced?**

Note: Values that contain spaces and/or apostrophes are being replaced.

I tried escaping the parentheses...

`$MatchFinal[$i] = str_replace("(", "\(", $MatchFinal[$i]);`

and

`$MatchFinal[$i] = str_replace(")", "\)", $MatchFinal[$i]);`

...but I received an error message:

`Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 51`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-quote.php)

```
$MatchFinal[$i] = preg_quote($MatchFinal[$i]);
```